# How to return array

Tags: javascript, testcomplete

I am using the below function to load xml and then return the array with values.
But when i call it in another function it gives error "arrXML is undefined".

```
function readXML() {
     // create an array object
     var arrXML = new Array();

     //create XML DOM object
     var docXML = Sys.OleObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");

     // load xml
     docXML.load("C:\\Users\\ankit\\Desktop\\read.xml");

     // search nodes with 'config' tag
     var Nodes = docXML.selectNodes("//config");
     for (i = 0; i < Nodes.length; i++){
         var ChildNodes = Nodes.item(i);
         arrXML[i] = Nodes(i).childNodes(0).text +":"+Nodes(i).childNodes(1).text;
     }
     // return array of XML elements
     return arrXML; 
}

function getvalues() {
    log.message(arrXML[1]);  // this line gives error
}
```

Comment: You are not checking to make sure that the document loaded correctly or that any of your variables ended up with data in them.

Comment: The doc is getting loaded successfully . if you print like log.message(readXML()[1]) , it prints the values in another function. but i do not want to call it like this. It should be directly called

Comment: `arrXML` is local to `readXML` because you declared it with `var` inside that block.  `getValues` has no idea it exists (because it no longer does)

Comment: Yes Gary , you are right, I took out var and now its printing the values . Thanks a lot.

Comment: Alternatively you could make arrXML global or pass it to whatever functions need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

`arrXML` is local to the function `readXML` because you declared it with the `var` keyword inside that block. `getValues` has no idea it exists (because it no longer does).

Your options are to make the variable global (which you should be careful with)

```
vinu = {}; // vinu is global namespace containing the array
function readXML() {
  vinu.arrXML = [];
  // ...
  return vinu.arrXML; // This might not even be necessary in this case
}

function getvalues() {
  log.message(vinu.arrXML[1]);
}
```

... or to pass the variable to the function when you call it.

```
function getvalues(arg) {
  log.message(arg[arrXML[1]]);
  return arg; // This function can't change the original variable, so use the return if need-be
}

// Somewhere that has access to the actual "arrXML"
getvalues(arrXML);
```

... or use a closure.